# simple silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, wcf, architecture

So, i'm building my first SL application.
I tried to use the MVVM approach, and I think that's the way for me.
Basically, it's a simple application which shows data to the user, the data source is local (maybe in the future will be centric, but right now this is not the case), and the data should be retrieved by:

**A.** Calling file system's reading

and

**B.** Method calls from External DLLs

So, as I said, I started to work with MVVM (used [this tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/the-mvvm-pattern/using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-applications)). I have 3 components: the service, the SL application and the project that host the SL app (excuse me if i'm not using the exact proffecional terms...).

**My question is:** Do you think that I've chose the right design? if so, is there any way not using IIS to host the service or is it a  must? (I don't want to spend time on adminastrative tasks on clients' computers), because as I said, the data is local at the moment and IIS feels unnecessary.

I'll appriciate every comment on this. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I'll try to simplify my question: I need my SL app to communicate with some kind of service - that will be able to take requests and reply back to the app.
This service suppose to be able to use .net dlls, and this service **should** be locally on each client run the app.

**EDIT:**
I noticed the [Self host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939340.aspx) option.
Does anyone has any experience with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to go with [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)(WPF XAML Browser Application).
It suited perfectly to my requirements:
1. no deployment issues - just press a link, and .net enviroment will do the rest (downloading the needed assemblies, install them and finally run the app)
2. it's hosted on a browser
3. no IIS is needed!!  it's a client-only application

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about: You having access to a database server somewhere, you should try [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services). This will allow you to create service for each entity and the service will get included into your host project or you can even create a WCF RIA library.

As suppose to your MVVM pattern. I prefer splitting my Views from my ViewModels In different projects. I like to see them as a seperate layer.

Comment: Thanks, Rikkos. I'm a silverlight starter, and not familiar with RIA services yet. Is this solution means that each client will have it's own service?

Comment: If this's the case, that's the solution i need.

Comment: Yes each, entity will have it's own DomainService as it is called in WCF RIA services. If you have your database it is quiete easy to start with and you will have your CRUD actions in no time. Here is a video if you haven't seen it yet. [link](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/net-ria-services-intro) It's is very insightful on what RIA has to offer and what it is capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using ria services may mean that you have a number of services which apply to one user, but yes they are specific to the user. Which file system would you be attempting to access? The client or the server?

Comment: that's the thing, that's not a client-server app. the file system is on the local network.